# How to sort with TinySort

Tags: jquery, html, tinysort

Given this view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Bootstrap.Base.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<OfficeOrdersViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="tc" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Office Order Summary
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="pc" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="server">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <legend>Office Order Summary</legend>

        <input type="hidden" value="<%: Model.OfficeId %>" name="OfficeId" id="OfficeId" />

        <div class="row-fluid" id="companySelect" name="companySelect" style="display: none;">
            <span class="span7">
                <label class="bold">Company</label>
                <input type="button" class="btn" id="btnFindCompany" value="Find a Company" style="margin-bottom: 3px;" />
                <input type="text" id="CompanySearch" class="input-block-level valid" placeholder="Search for a company" style="display: none;" minlength="2" maxlength="100" /><br />
                <select id="CustomerInput_CompanyId" name="CustomerInput.CompanyId" class="input-block-level valid" style="display: none;"></select>
                <input type="button" id="btnUseCompany" name="btnUseCompany" value="Next" class="btn btn-success" style="display: none;" />
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid" id="companyData" name="companyData" style="display: none;">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4 forceWordWrap">
                    <h4 style="margin: 0;"><span name="OfficeName" id="OfficeName"><%: Model.OfficeName %></span></h4>
                    <span name="OfficeAddress1" id="OfficeAddress1"><%: Model.OfficeAddress1 %></span>
                    <span name="OfficeAddress2" id="OfficeAddress2"> <%: Model.OfficeAddress2 %></span><br />
                    <span name="OfficeCity" id="OfficeCity"><%: Model.OfficeCity %></span>,
                    <span name="OfficeState" id="OfficeState"><%: Model.OfficeState %></span>
                    <span name="OfficeZip" id="OfficeZip"> <%: Model.OfficeZip %></span><br />
                    <span name="OfficePhone" id="OfficePhone"></span><%: Model.OfficePhone %><br />
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span6 bold textRight">
                            Office Sales Executive:<br />
                            Office Order Count:<br />
                            Office Revenue:<br />
                            Active Agents:
                        </div>
                        <div class="span6 forceWordWrap">
                            <span name="SalesRepFirstName" id="SalesRepFirstName"><%: Model.SalesRepFirstName %> </span><span name="SalesRepLastName" id="SalesRepLastName"><%: Model.SalesRepLastName %></span><br />
                            <span name="OrderCount" id="OrderCount"><%: (Model.AgentOrders != null) ? Model.AgentOrders.Count() : 0 %></span><br />
                            <span name="OfficeRevenue" id="OfficeRevenue"><%: (Model.AgentOrders != null) ? Model.AgentOrders.Sum(ao => ao.PeriodOrderRevenue) : 0 %></span><br />
                            <span name="AgentsCount" id="AgentsCount"><%: Model.AgentsCount %></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span4"><h4>Orders For:</h4></div>
                        <div class="span4"><input type="button" id="btn90" name="btn90" value="Last 90 Days" class="btn btn-success" style="font-size: 12px; width: 99%; text-align: center;" /></div>
                        <div class="span4"><input type="button" id="btn12" name="btn12" value="Last 12 Months" class="btn btn-inverse" style="font-size: 12px; width: 99%; text-align: center;" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span4"><input type="button" id="btn30" name="btn30" value="Last 30 Days" class="btn btn-inverse" style="font-size: 12px; width: 99%; text-align: center;" /></div>
                        <div class="span4"><input type="button" id="btn6" name="btn6" value="Last 6 Months" class="btn btn-inverse" style="font-size: 12px; width: 99%; text-align: center;" /></div>
                        <div class="span4"><input type="button" id="btnYTD" name="btnYTD" value="Year to Date" class="btn btn-inverse" style="font-size: 12px; width: 99%; text-align: center;" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="AgentList" name="AgentList">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Customer</th>
                            <th>Sales Executive</th>
                            <th>Last Order Opened</th>
                            <th>Revenue</th>
                            <th>LB Orders</th>
                            <th>SB Orders</th>
                            <th>Total Orders</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <% if (Model.AgentOrders != null) {
                           foreach (var agent in Model.AgentOrders) { %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="/customerhistory#/details/<%: agent.CustomerId %>" class="btn btn-success input-medium">
                                <span name="firstName" id="firstName"><%: agent.CustomerFirstName %></span> <span name="lastName" id="lastName"><%: agent.CustomerLastName %></span>
                            </a></td>
                            <td><%: agent.SalesRepFirstName %> <%: agent.SalesRepLastName %></td>
                            <td><%: agent.NewestOrderOpenDate %></td>
                            <td><%: agent.PeriodOrderRevenue %></td>
                            <td><%: agent.PeriodLBOrderCount %></td>
                            <td><%: agent.PeriodSBOrderCount %></td>
                            <td><%: agent.PeriodLBOrderCount + agent.PeriodSBOrderCount %></td>
                        </tr>
                    <%      }
                        } %>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdditionalScripts" runat="server">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/additional-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.tinysort.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <%--<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.sortElements.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            ShowHideCompanySelect();

            $("#CustomerInput_CompanyId").hide();
            $("#CompanySearch").hide();
            $("#btnUseCompany").hide();
            $("#frmCompanySelect div.companysearchError").hide();

            $("#btnFindCompany").click(function () {
                $("#CustomerInput_CompanyId").hide();
                $("#CompanySearch").show();
                $("#btnFindCompany").hide();
            });

            $("#CompanySearch").autocomplete({
                source: '/OfficeOrders/OfficeSearch?' + $("#CompanySearch").val(),
                minLength: 2,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#CustomerInput_CompanyId")
                        .find('option')
                        .remove()
                        .end()
                        .append($("<option value=" + ui.item.id + ">" + ui.item.value + "</option>"))
                        .val(ui.item.id);
                    $("#CustomerInput_CompanyId").show();
                    $("#CompanySearch").hide();
                    $("#btnFindCompany").show();
                    $("#btnFindCompany").prop("value", "Find Another Company");
                    $("#btnUseCompany").show();
                }
            });

            $("#btnUseCompany").click(function () {
                $.post('/OfficeOrders/GetOfficeData', {
                    officeId: $("#CustomerInput_CompanyId").val()
                }, function(data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        $("#OfficeId").text(data.officeDto.OfficeId);
                        $("#OfficeName").text(data.officeDto.OfficeName);
                        $("#OfficeAddress1").text(data.officeDto.OfficeAddress1);
                        $("#OfficeAddress2").text(data.officeDto.OfficeAddress2);
                        $("#OfficeCity").text(data.officeDto.OfficeCity);
                        $("#OfficeState").text(data.officeDto.OfficeState);
                        $("#OfficeZip").text(data.officeDto.OfficeZip);
                        $("#OfficePhone").text(data.officeDto.OfficePhone);
                        $("#Agents").text(data.officeDto.Agents);
                        $("#AgentsCount").text(data.officeDto.AgentsCount);
                        $("#SalesRepFirstName").text(data.officeDto.SalesRepFirstName);
                        $("#SalesRepLastName").text(data.officeDto.SalesRepLastName);
                        $("#OrderCount").text(data.officeDto.OrderCount);
                        $("#OfficeRevenue").text(data.officeDto.OfficeRevenue);


                        $("#OfficeId").val($("#CustomerInput_CompanyId").val());
                        ShowHideCompanySelect();
                    } else {
                        ShowHideCompanySelect();
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        function ShowHideCompanySelect() {
            if ($("#OfficeId").val() === "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") {
                $("#companySelect").show();
                $("#companyData").hide();
            } else {
                $("#companySelect").hide();
                $("#companyData").show();
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            //Start Sorting for the table

            var table = document.getElementById('AgentList'),
                tableHead = table.querySelector('thead'),
                tableHeaders = tableHead.querySelectorAll('th'),
                tableBody = table.querySelector('tbody');

            tableHead.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                var tableHeader = e.target,
                    textContent = tableHeader.textContent,
                    tableHeaderIndex,
                    isAscending,
                    order;

                if (textContent !== 'add row') {
                    while (tableHeader.nodeName !== 'TH') {
                        tableHeader = tableHeader.parentNode;
                    }

                    tableHeaderIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(tableHeaders, tableHeader);
                    isAscending = tableHeader.getAttribute('data-order') === 'asc';
                    order = isAscending ? 'desc' : 'asc';
                    tableHeader.setAttribute('data-order', order);

                    tinysort(
                        tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr'), {
                            selector: 'td:nth-child(' + (tableHeaderIndex + 1) + ')',
                            order: order
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
            //End Sorting for the table
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="ac" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdditionalContent" runat="server">
    <style>
        .ui-menu {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 2px;
            margin: 0;
            display: block;
            float: left;
        }
        .ui-menu .ui-menu {
            margin-top: 03px;
        }
        .ui-menu {
            margin: 3px;
            padding: 3px;
            zoom: 1;
            float: left;
            clear: left;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
            border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
        }
        .ui-menu-item
        {
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
        }
        .ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            padding: .2em .4em;
            line-height: 1.5;
            zoom: 1;
        }
        .ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-hover,
        .ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-active {
            font-weight: normal;
            margin: -1px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
```

I get the following error when clicking on the headers:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: tinysort is not defined

I am not really sure why that would be, since `tinysort.min.js` ends with:
`a.fn.TinySort=a.fn.Tinysort=a.fn.tsort=a.fn.tinysort}(jQuery);`
Which I take to mean "for all of these case-different spellings of tinysort".

Could use a hand sorting this out. No pun intended.

FYI: the jquery I'm using is almost exactly what's in place on [TinySort's page.](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/index.html#sorting-tables)

Comment: Where do you have <script> tag of it?

Comment: This is an MVC view, so it's in a ContentPlaceholder for scripts. I'll amend to show the entire View. `Update` - Amended.

Comment: I don't believe "//ajax...." works. Try with this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp . Search for Google CDN

Comment: been using that for jquery stuff for quite a while in our project - works great.

Comment: In fact, the OTHER jquery stuff on the page utterly fails to work without that specific tag in place. With it, the other goodies on the page work fantastically. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the Tinysort script is not added. The current version of Tinysort is standalone. But that does mean that the current jquery.tinysort.js requires tinysort.js. So add the latter and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'm a tad confused there, as the only script I'm using in other Views in my site to call up tinysort is `<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.tinysort.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`, which is in the list of scripts I'm including in this view.

Comment: That said, I've downloaded the full git repo for TinySort, and dropped the tinysort.js in my project. Checking it now.

Comment: Adding in tinysort.js did the trick. I'm still insanely curious as to how other views I have do their sorting with just the jquery.tinysort.min.js, but I'll hold that curiosity for another day. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming in your snippet that `jQuery` is being passed in to a function which accepts the `jQuery` object as a parameter called `a` in your `../../Scripts/jquery.tinysort.min.js` file:

```
(function(a){
...
a.fn.TinySort=a.fn.Tinysort=a.fn.tsort=a.fn.tinysort}(jQuery);
})(jQuery);
```

Then I believe the problem is that you are trying to use `tinysort`, i.e. `window.tinysort` which is not defined so you get the `ReferenceError`. The tiny sort functionality was added as a jQuery plug-in functionality to the `jQuery` object. So,

```
jQuery.tinysort(
    tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr'),
    {
        selector: 'td:nth-child(' + (tableHeaderIndex + 1) + ')',
        order: order
    }
);
```

should work instead of `tinysort(...);`

Comment: I've updated the code above to show the entire View, so all the code is visible. No snippets here! :)